# Isn't This New Relativistic Formulation of NS-Equations, Solution of Navier-Stokes Existence and smoothness problem?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

[Estakhr Material-Geodesic Equation](http://bit.ly/1bfqK25) is a new type of geodesic equation, with new and relevant degrees of freedom, that describes the behavior of a fluid for large times, this new approach to solving the equations that would let us understand what are really key properties of a turbulent fluid.

Isn't this equation solution of Navier-Stokes Existence and Smoothness problem?